# vue cli3 lib with IE11 support

Tags: internet-explorer-11, vue-cli-3

According to the documentation (https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library), it's not clear to me how to integrate babel to make the lib built be IE11-friendly... I have to make a npm package from a Vue component.

My npm script in package.json is:
    `vue-cli-service build --target lib src/MyComponent.vue`

I've put a correct "browserslist" in package.json.

It seems that I have to use a babel.config.js with a preset.

Not sure of what to install as dev dependencies and what to configure...

Anyone has a working sample lib or some guidance, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering to myself :-) It was documented but at several places. So...

- Add these dev dependencies:

`npm install --save-dev @vue/cli-plugin-babel @babel/preset-env`

- Add this dependency:

`npm install --save @babel/polyfill current-script-polyfill`

- In your main Vue file, `import 'current-script-polyfill'` before anything else
- Indeed define a `browserslist` in package.json
- Indeed have a `babel.config.js` with

```
    presets: [
      ['@vue/app']
    ]
  }
```

**Edit** : now we use a `.browserlistrc` file instead of definition in package.json. Here is what we use, thanks for asking:

```
> 1%
last 2 versions
not ie < 11
```

Comment: I suggest that you coud mark your answer as solution if it solved your problem, and this will be helpful for someone meets with the same problem.

Comment: @redshift thanks for your question, I edited with the information

Comment: For Vuetify I had one last step: add this line to vue.config.js  as per https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#ie-11-safari-9-support transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],